# Ruta not able to find white space

Tags: uima, ruta

I want to rule to trigger on white space.
for sentence:"My name is Prabhav."

Here is my ruta code:

```
 DECLARE Alert(STRING comment);


    (WS{->LOG("WS")} )
    {-> CREATE(Alert,1,2,3,"comment"="Space not allowed")};
```

note:
I think code is syntactically ok because it works fine if I use "ANY"
Instead of "WS".

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespaces are not visible by default. You need to remove them from the filtered types, e.g., with RETAINTYPE:

```
DECLARE Alert(STRING comment);
RETAINTYPE(WS);
WS{->LOG("WS"), CREATE(Alert,"comment"="Space not allowed")};
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*